# incorrect reading from input file

Tags: file, input

Trying to read from inputFile that has multiple lines but program only reads the first 4 into Strings and double correctly
inputFile is as such
hv1044
jerry sein
B
100500
hv8745
mary kay
C
50000
P

I've tried moving the while statement and tried adding a do while loop but it still only reads the first 4 lines of the input file correctly.

Output is suppose to look like
but will only output the first 4 lines correct
Employee:       Jerry Sein
Position:       Associate
Salary:         $100000.00
Email Address:  J-Sein@hv.com

---

Code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class KosakowskiRunEmployee
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    
    File file = new File("employeeInput.txt");
    
    double pay = 0 ;
    
    if (file.exists())
    {
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
      
      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
        
        String id = inputFile.nextLine();
        String name = inputFile.nextLine();
        String lvl = inputFile.nextLine();

                  
        System.out.println("Employee: \t\t" + name);
        System.out.print("Position: \t\t");
                
        switch (lvl)
        {
          case "A":
            System.out.print("Executive");
            break;

          case "B":
            System.out.print("Associate");
            break;

          case "C":
            System.out.print("Assistant");
            break;

          case "D":
            System.out.print("Intern");
            break;
  
          default:
          break;
        }

        System.out.println();
        
        pay = inputFile.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Salary: \t\t" + "$" + "%.2f", pay);
        System.out.println();
        
        String[] sp  = name.split(" ");
        int n = name.length();
        char first = name.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Email Address: \t" + first + "-" + sp[1] +  "@hv.com");
        System.out.println("______________________________________");
      }
      inputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("The file you are looking for does not exist.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I just had to add
inputFile.nextLine();
after
System.out.println("______________________________________");
to eat up a line. Then everything lined up and worked like it should.